# Strange filter applied to images by EE uploaded via File Manager - mystery!

Tags: image

I’ve got an EE 2.5.2 site running on Dreamhost which we upgraded a while ago from 1.6.x. Ever since doing so all the images we upload via the File Manager seem to get some weird filter applied to them, and they end up looking like [this](http://www.hoots.ca/images/uploads/projects/DSC03174.JPG).

Anyone else experience this problem or have a clue how to solve it?

Comment: Have you made sure to synchronise the file upload directory?

Comment: yes, in fact I believe everything got weird as soon as I applied the synchronization, and thereafter any images that I upload or use the image editor on get the weird filter applied.

Comment: What version of the GD library and/or ImageMagick do you have installed? What happens if you try to use an image resizing add-on such as CE Image on an image you upload via FTP? This could help isolate the problem.

Comment: I'm running GD Version "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)"

Comment: I've just tried running an image through CE Image and no errors were returned. It did indeed resize the image, however, because all of the images are getting the weird filter applied once they're uploaded, the resized image via CE Image still has the filter (because that's what was fed into it).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a filter enabled for that file upload in the settings. Check to make sure there is not an [**Image Manipulation**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#image-manipulations) setting enabled in your File Upload Preferences by accident.

Also, if you are only seeing this image on the frontend and not in the control panel, check to see if you are using CE Image or some other image manipulation code that is possibly changing the image display.

---

**UPDATE:** I suggest that you upgrade to ExpressionEngine v2.5.5 to eliminate a bug in your EE version as the issue. This seems very unique to your server setup and EE install so upgrading EE is the first step.

Comment: @mediagirl - the only setting I have is "Maximum Image Width (in pixels)". This happens in the CP. I'm not using any image manipulation (or plugins) on the front-end at all.

Comment: Is this filter only on the thumbnail or on the main image as well. If you FTP to the server and download the image is the filter visible?

Comment: The filter is on the main image and, indeed, the image on the server (via ftp) has been filtered.

Comment: Very odd. I've never seen this ever.

Comment: Yeah - me neither!  Many EE sites, and never this.

Comment: Does this happen using when you run the same site either locally or in a dev/staging environment? Or is it only running the site live on Dreamhost that the filtering occurs?

Comment: Also... do you have any watermark preferences set at all (even if you are not applying them to uploaded images)?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a setting for ImageMagick was triggered or set somewhere, maybe in the .htaccess or the php.ini file.

Comment: There is no php.ini file that I can see on the server (via ftp) or that I would have ever touched. I'm only seeing this on the live site, we don't have a local dev/stage setup. There are zero watermark prefs setup.

In my tests, when I upload an image to the CP it does not get filtered right away, it's only if I use EE's image resizing tool (in the CP) that the filter gets applied.  If I resize the image with CE Image then no filter gets applied.

Comment: Can you send me one of the problem image so I can test on my end? anna at mediagirl dot com.

Comment: I just tested an image upload on EE v 2.5.3 and it worked fine. I'd suggest that you upgrade to the most recent version of EE to eliminate a bug as the issue.

Comment: I'm running EE 2.5.3 on numerous other sites and not having the issue either. I'm quite certain it's the server environment, but I just can't quite pin down where or what the issue is as I'd like to approach the web host (Dreamhost) to find out, without getting the usual push back one gets from hosts that the problem is the CMS, which I don't believe is the case here.